# Make a cookie expire in one hour

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have some code for a cookie that i want to make expire in 1 hour the code is:

```
    function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    }

    function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
    }

    sWhere = "http://google.com";

    if(!readCookie('viewcheck')){
    createCookie('viewcheck',1,1);
    } else {
    window.location = sWhere;
    }
```

How can i make the cookie expire in an hour?

Comment: If the function really takes days and it works, try passing 1/24 to get one hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is using a `days` argument that is only changing minutes, not days since `60*1000` is 60 seconds in milliseconds.
You should rename that argument to `minutes`, and then you can easily see that you just need to multiply the numberof hours by 60.